# testing with random generated test inputs

Tags: c#, testing

I created a function that generates random numbers. I plan to use these random numbers as input for my program, to test different inputs.

How can I accomplish this?

This is the program I would like to test.

```
public void Debit(double amount)
{
    if (m_frozen)
    {
        throw new Exception("Account frozen");
    }

    if (amount > m_balance)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("amount");
    }

    if (amount < 0)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("amount");
    }

    m_balance += amount;
}
```

This is the function which generated random numbers:

```
using System;
namespace Csharp.RandomExample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(GenerateRandomNumber());
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static int GenerateRandomNumber()
        {
            Random randomNumber = new Random();
            return randomNumber.Next();
        }
    }
}
```

The numbers this function generates must be used as test inputs for two variables(amount and balance).

Comment: Do you mean a unit test or some kind of automated test? If so how could you ever verify the result from random input?

Comment: I should make automated test using automated tool. But every time when I test my method, the result is 60,70% code coverage.I was given an advice to make this type of random method which will create random values as inputs of my method.With this random method I expect greater code coverage. Can you help me how to solve that by random method???Thanks for writing

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you just need to pass the return value of the GenerateRandomNumber() method to your Debit() method

```
 for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
 {
    Debit((double)GenerateRandomNumber());
 }
```

Just noticed the edit to your original post. Its not clear in your code where m_amount and m_balance are being set but you can just use the result from your GenerateRandomNumber() method to set them.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
{
     int testNumber = GenerateRandomNumber();
     m_Amount = m_Balance = testNumber;
     Debit(doubleValueYouWantToTest);
}
```

Comment: I still couldn't solve my problem.Is this works for you?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are creating a new `Random` instance within `GenerateRandomNumber`.  `Random` is seeded based on the system time, and the value it uses is only updated every few milliseconds.  You're asking for more than one value every few milliseconds.

You should create a single instance of `Random` and then call `Next` on that one instance repeatedly.  In your case you can just make a `private static Random randomNumber = new Random()` just before the method and it will take care of that problem.

Comment: That is one problem. But the question asks how he can use the random numbers to test his class `Debit` code, and you haven't addressed that at this time.

Comment: I don't know how to addressed random numbers with two variables amount and balance. I need code for that

Comment: Also I would use an explicit seed. In case the test reveals an error, you should be able to reproduce its behavior. If you use new random numbers every time and the error occurs every one millionth time, you have a problem.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes That problem is also solved by just logging the seed.  If you use a hard coded value then every run of the program has the same output.  That's great for testing, but often poor for production apps.

Comment: @Servy. Logging the seed is a good solution as well. This code is thought to be for testing only. I don't think customers would appreciate random debits.

Answer (score 0):

Creating random inputs for your tests isn't good way to increase code coverage. In fact it isn't good practice to use random values in any unit tests but maybe some that have something to do with threading.

In your case it is simple to have 100% code coverage with few simple tests.

1. Account is frozen (balance and amount don't matter)
2. Amount > balance
3. Amount = balance (edge case)
4. Amount < balance
5. Amount = 0 (edge case)
6. Amount < 0

If you use random inputs you never have guarantee that you tested all paths.

Comment: I know that your test will realize 100% code coverage.But simply I have to use some kind of random method which will produce the inputs for the method.If you have some idea please help to solve my real problem.Have you ever used random method to create test's input?

Comment: No I have not used random input for my tests because it doesn't make sense.